# C pointer address printing

Tags: c, pointers

Are all the commented explanations here correct?

```c
int x = 1, y = 2;

int *ip; //declares *ip as an int type?

ip = &x; //assigns the address of x to ip?

y = *ip; //y is now 1 via dereferencing
```

What happens if I print the result of `ip`? Will it print the address of variable `x`, something like:

```
011001110
```

Comment: Curious why you don't try it?

Comment: I would word the first comment as "declares ip as a pointer-to-int type". The rest looks fine. As far as printing `ip`, yes, you get the address of `x`. The format of the address all depends upon what format string you use to print it. You can write it in decimal, hex, or whatever.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Yes. All of your statements are correct. However in the first case
int *ip;

it is better to say that `ip` is a pointer to an `int` type.

> What happens if I print the result of ip?

It will print the address of `x`.

> Will it print the address of variable x, something like

```
011001110
```

No. Addresses are generally represented in hexadecimal. You should use `%p` specifier to print the address.

```
printf("Address of x is %p\n", (void *)ip);
```

---

**NOTE:**
Note that in the above declaration `*` is not the indirection operator. Instead it specify the type of `p`, telling the compiler that `p` is a *pointer to `int`*. The `*` symbol performs indirection only when it appears in a statement.

Comment: Can't I just say: int ip; Instead of int *ip? After all * is defined as the de-referencing unary operator not a type specifier.

Comment: No. `*` in the declaration is not a dereference operator.

Comment: @robertrocha Exactly.

Comment: @robertrocha There's no pointer *type*.  There are pointers to *types*.

Answer (score 4):

```
int x = 1, y = 2;

int *ip; // declares ip as a pointer to an int (holds an address of an int)

ip = &x; // ip now holds the address of x

y = *ip; // y now equals the value held at the address in ip
```

Answer (score 2):

Consider the following as an example:

```
Initializer       x        y        ip
Memory Value      [1]      [2]      [1000]
Memory Address    1000     1004     1008
```

As you can see:

1. `x` has the value `1` and the address `1000`
2. `y` has the value `2` and the address `1004`
3. `ip` has the value `1000` (the address of `x`) and the address `1008`

Consider the following:

1. `x == 1` and `&x == 1000`
2. `y == 2` and `&y == 1004`
3. `ip == 1000` and `&ip == 1008` and `*ip == 1` (the value of `x`)

Hope this helps you visualize what's happening.

Answer (score 0):

It's all correct.

1st line: you declare two variables

2nd line: a memory pointer "ip" is defined

3rd line: The memory adress of X is given to the pointer ip

4th line: Y is now set to the value of the variable X at the address ip

The memory address, however, is in hexadecimal format. 011001110 is a byte of data and not a memory address. The address is more likely going to be something like 0x000000000022FE38 (it may be shorter). Consider this:

```
int x = 0;
int *ptr = &x; //the "&" character means "the address of"
printf("The variable X is at 0x%p and has the value of %i", (void *)ptr, x);
```

This would print the address of X, rather than *ptr. You'd need another pointer to print the address of *ptr. But that's rather pointless, as a pointer is defined to print the address of a variable. Think of it as an alias for another variable (it's value is the value at that memory address).

Answer (score 0):

I like the original poster's statement that `*ip` is an `int`. This accurately reflects the semantics of declarations, where the declarator `*ip` is an expression and the declaration specifier(s), in this case `int`, provide the type of the expression. Stating the meaning this way provides insight into the meaning of something like `int *ip, q;` where `q` is simply an `int`. You might not want to use this more formal way of stating the type in conversation, but it is helpful in seeing the underlying structure expressed by the declaration.

Answer (score 0):

Despite the title, this is also tagged c++ and the top search result for "c++ print pointer address", so for that language you can pass directly to `std::cout`:

```cpp
int x = 1;
int* y = &x;

std::cout << "The address of x is " << &x << std::endl
          << "        and is also " << y << std::endl;
```

Potential output:

```
The address of x is 0x7ffe9eb117e4
        and is also 0x7ffe9eb117e4
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/vGEGh83s4)